# Java: searching for config files: linux vs windows

Tags: java, configuration, configuration-files

For a small utility I'm building, I need to read a config/ini file. This in itself is no problem, but I'm trying to figure out how to properly/best do this on both Linux and Windows.

Under Linux the location of this file could be:

```
- /etc
- the install directory of the jars/files
```

Under Windows, I have no idea what the equivalent of /etc is (sorry, I do all my work on Linux).

Does anybody know of a component which will search common file locations for config/ini files which I could reuse in my code?

Many thanks
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a System Property to do it.

```
String basepath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Take a look at

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: Thanks for a quick and straight forward answer.